# Ошибка подключения через docker

Tags: java, docker

Есть проект:
Сервер статистики: слушает localhost:9090:9090
БД для сервера статистики, слушает localhost:6542:5432
Сервер основного класса: слушает localhost:8080:8080
БД для сервера основного класса: слушает localhost:6541:5432

В методе основного класса есть POST запрос на localhost:9090/hit, собственно когда все находится в докере, то возникает ошибка

```
2023-08-10 08:48:08.135 ERROR 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "http://localhost:9090/hit": Connect to localhost:9090 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:9090 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)] with root cause
2023-08-10T08:48:08.136845800Z 
2023-08-10T08:48:08.136860600Z java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

Если запустить main класс не в докере, а в intellij idea, то ошибки нет, обращается без проблем, помогите исправить ситуацию.

docker-compose.yml

`version: '3.1'
services:
stats-service:
build: stats-service/server
container_name: stats-server-container
ports:
- "9090:9090"
depends_on:
- stats-db
environment:
- SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://stats-db:5432/stats-db
- SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=stats
- SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=stats`

stats-db:
image: postgres:14-alpine
container_name: stats-db-container
volumes:
- ./stats-service/server/src/main/resources/schema.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/schema.sql
- /var/lib/postgresql/data/
ports:
- "6541:5432"
environment:
- POSTGRES_DB=stats-db
- POSTGRES_USER=stats
- POSTGRES_PASSWORD=stats

main-db:
image: postgres:14-alpine
container_name: main-db-container
volumes:
- ./main-service/src/main/resources/schema.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/schema.sql
- /var/lib/postgresql/data/
ports:
- "6542:5432"
environment:
- POSTGRES_DB=main-db
- POSTGRES_USER=main
- POSTGRES_PASSWORD=main

main-service:
build: main-service
container_name: main-service-container
ports:
- "8080:8080"
depends_on:
- main-db
environment:
- SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://main-db:5432/main-db
- SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=main
- SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=main

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда у вас все находится в Докере, вы не сможете достучаться до вашего сервера статистики по localhost:9090/hit. Вам нужно стучаться по имени сервиса: в вашем случае это будет:  stats-service:9090/hit

Каждый сервис в вашем докере заключен в свой собственный контейнер, со своей собственной изолированной сетью. Чтобы легче было представить, каждый сервис - это отдельная виртуальная машина. Соотетственно вы когда отправляете запрос на локалхост, вы стучитесь не в stats-service, а в main-service, а в нем у вас на 9090 порту ничего нет.

Comment: Так вот и я о чем, они в разных же контейнерах, контейнер с сервером слушает 8080 порт, он доступен извне, собственно все равно не могу понять, почему основной сервер не может достучаться по физическому адресу? Или в докер есть ограничение, которое не позволяет отправлять запросы из контейнера по физическому адресу ?

Comment: Но за наводку спасибо, попробую реализовать сегодня, отпишусь, получилось или нет

Comment: @SyBeRGEN Каждый контейнер в докере имеет свою соственную изолированную сеть. И использование локалхост отправляет запрос самому себе (в этот же самый контейнер, откуда был отправлен запрос).

Comment: Теперь понял, спасибо

Comment: Все получилось!